# Merge arrays if not nil and not empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

There are some arrays in Ruby (is this case there 4 array)

```
array1 = [{key="label1.1", value="label1.2"}, {key="label1.2", value="label1.2"}]
array2 = [{key="label2.1", value="label2.2"}]

array3 = []
array4 = nil
result_array = array1 | array2 | array3 | array4
```

Each of arrays has the same structure as others: it's hash values. How many elements in it, if it's nil or empty - it's not known.

So I need `result_array`  to look:

`[{key="label1.1", value="label1.2"}, {key="label1.2", value="label1.2"}, {key="label2.1", value="label2.2"}]`

However that code is going to cause an exception because `array4` is equal to `nil`.

Is there any, Ruby, way to check if an array is not nil and not empty and if so, then  merge it to `result_array`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
[array1, array2, array3, array4].compact.reduce([], :|)
```

Comment: Wonderful. Gonna try to remember that.

Comment: To handle the corner case when all the `arrayX` are `nil`, use `reduce([], :|)`

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think about this case, thanks for correction :)

Answer (score 4):

Kernel defines a method called `Array` which will leave the arrays alone, but convert the nil into an empty array.

```
array1 = [{:key => "label1.1", :value => "label1.2"}, {:key =>"label1.2", :value => "label1.2"}]
array2 = [{:key => "label2.1", :value => "label2.2"}]

array3 = []
array4 = nil
result_array = Array(array1) | Array(array2) | Array(array3) | Array(array4)
result_array # => [{:key=>"label1.1", :value=>"label1.2"}, {:key=>"label1.2", :value=>"label1.2"}, {:key=>"label2.1", :value=>"label2.2"}]
```