# What does `:|` do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

I found the following syntax in another question, and I have been unable to find any documentation on what its doing - I'm assuming syntactic sugar of some sort:

`[array1, array2, array3, array4].compact.reduce([], :|)`

I allows for one of the arrays to be `nil` instead of an array, and seems to work like a charm. Can anyone point me in the right direction to understand what is going on?

The original question is here: [Merge arrays if not nil and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228709/merge-arrays-if-not-nil-and-not-empty)

Comment: Link to docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Comment: Interesting find! For the record though, it's more readable to just use `array#flatten`, which _looks_ like it's equivalent.

Comment: @Jules: nope, not flattening. Here it's a union of the arrays.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-7C

Comment: Your title should be, "What does `Array#|` do?" (though that could be improved). `Array` is not the only class with a method named `:!` (There is [Integer#!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-7C), for example.)  "Ruby" in the title is redundant because it is one of your tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a symbol, like `:test`, but a single character symbol.

The two-argument version of `reduce` accepts as a second argument a method name, the name of the method in this case is `:|`, or the `|` method. `|` on arrays is a set operation, it "or"s the arrays together, giving you the unique superset of all elements contained in both arrays. This isn't a particularly idiomatic use of `reduce`, you could achieve the same thing with `.flatten.uniq`

If you wanted to add the numbers, you could use `:+`, or to multiply you could use `:*`.

Comment: It worth it to mention, that the first argument in this particular call to `reduce` is redundant, `...reduce(:|)` is fine enough. Also, `flatten.uniq` is worth by any mean (unless we are positive all the arrays are tiny.) It might consume quadratic amount of memory compared to `reduce`.

Comment: @mudasobwa the first argument is necessary in the case where the input array is empty, but you want `reduce` to return an array regardless.

Comment: @meager if the first array was empty (`[]`) it would still return an array. If it was nil, that's a different story. In that case the elements being iterated over don't have the same interface so it'd possibly raise a NoMethodError anyway

Comment: @maxpleaner I'm talking about the **input array being empty**. `[].reduce(:|) #=> nil` vs `[].reduce([], :|) # => []`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing as this:

```
[array1, array2, array3, array4].compact.reduce([]) do |memo, array|
  memo | array
end
```

Although it has syntactic sugar, `Array#|` is a method which you can see the docs for [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C). As the docs say:

> Set Union — Returns a new array by joining ary with other_ary, excluding any duplicates and preserving the order from the original array

When the block of reduce takes this particular form (calling a single method on memo, passing the iteration's element as an argument), you can omit the block and just pass the method name.